# Why isn't this tweet from one user that's retweeted by another user showing up in the first user's Twitter timeline?

Tags: twitter

I really don't use Twitter much and am still struggling with some of its quirkiness.  I'd like to know why a particular tweet from a user doesn't show up in the user's own timeline.

Let's call him "[User A](https://twitter.com/billtilley1973)": the tweet is his very first tweet on 19 May 2016, let's call it "[Tweet #1](https://twitter.com/billtilley1973/status/733362022574923777)".  That tweet was, I guess, re-tweeted, replied to, or otherwise embedded in another tweet -- let's call it "[Tweet #2](https://twitter.com/BenjaminAhr/status/733376816136740865)" -- from another user -- "[User B](https://twitter.com/BenjaminAhr)" -- also on 19 May 2016.  Then on 20 May 2016, User A replied/retweeted/embedded Tweet #2 in yet another tweet, "[Tweet #3](https://twitter.com/billtilley1973/status/733684487566024706)".  So we have three tweets here, two from User A (Tweet's #1 and #3), and one in the middle (Tweet #2) from User B.

If I look at User A's timeline, all the way at the bottom, I don't see Tweet #1 anywhere; I see a different tweet (Tweet #1a) and Tweet #3 in succession.

Why isn't Tweet #1 at the very bottom of User A's timeline?

Comment: Did you look under "Tweets" or "Tweets and Replies?" The same tweets don't always show up in both tabs.